# How to send a continuous stream to a ASP Core REST API

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, streaming

I am trying to send a continuous stream, from a C# application, to an ASP Core REST API.

I define a continuous stream as for example someone talking into a microphone and the sound being sent directly, without being saved to a local file) to the Rest API to be saved to file.

I have been searching a lot on Google for something like that and so far could not find anything really useful.

I have been trying to emulate it by sending a large file (297MB).

This is what I have so far for the client side:

```
string TARGETURL = "http://localhost:58000/api/file/";
string filePath = @"G:\Voice\Samples\The Monkey's Paw.wav";

byte[] fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
var dummyStream = new MemoryStream(fileContent);
var inputData = new StreamContent(dummyStream);
HttpResponseMessage response = this._httpClient.PostAsync(TARGETURL, inputData).Result;
HttpContent result = response.Content;

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
  string contents = result.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
else
{
  // do something
}
```

And for the server side:

```
[Route("")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> Post()
{
  Dictionary<string, object> rv = new Dictionary<string, object>();

  try
  {
    string file = Path.Combine(@"G:\Voice\Samples\dummy.txt");
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write,
        FileShare.None, 4096, useAsync: true))
    {
      await Request.Body.CopyToAsync(fs);
    }

    // complete the transaction
    rv.Add("success", true);
    rv.Add("error", "");
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
  }
  return Json(rv);
}
```

When I am sending the file, the server throw the following exception:

> The request's Content-Length 304137380 is larger than the request body size limit 30000000.

I know that I could increase the body size limit, but that's not a longer term solution as the stream length could get longer that any limit I set.

That's why I am trying to find a solution that send the stream by chunks for the server to rebuild and write to a file.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is use a different network stack. A web application is always going to try and fit everything into HTTP. This is a very specific kind of way to communicate. And REST is built on top of these ideas as well. Things are generally though of as a document with references on the Internet, and REST is an extension to this idea.

It does however sit on top of some other great technologies that might suit your need better.

There's nothing to stop you using the internet, but maybe you need to look at possibly a UDP or TCP level implementation. Be aware that you will still be sending information in packets. There is no such thing as a constant stream of bits on the internet. A sound wave in the real world is an infinite thing, but computers are rubbish at that.

Maybe start by taking a look [at using sockets](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10649/An-Introduction-to-Socket-Programming-in-NET-using) and a library like [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio).